# SDL freeing surfaces on destructor fails

Tags: c++, sdl

1. If I fail to call a `SDL_FreeSurface(sprite)` before I `SDL_Quit()` and end program, will I have a leak? Or does exiting always free it? What if it crashes? I'm wondering in the case of it crashing, then `cleanup()` wouldn't be called.
2. Should my cleanup always be in the destructor? No cleanup function, unless I want to free some textures mid-game?
3. It says it's safe to pass NULL to  `SDL_FreeSurface()`, I added a NULL check, but it crashes anyway. I think the crash is a because is I need to manually set sprite to NULL after SDL_FreeSurface()?
4. It might be unrelated, (didn't seem to fix it) but the FAQ says: "You need to pass the SDL_INIT_NOPARACHUTE flag to your calls to SDL_Init() to make the msvc debugger work. "

note: I'm using c++ (not c) code where possible. The answers I found were using c-code.

```
class Game {
public:
    #...
private:
    SDL_Surface* screen;
    SDL_Surface* sprite;
};

Game::Game()
{
    done = false;
    sprite = NULL;
    screen = NULL;
}

Game::~Game()
{
    if(sprite != NULL){
        cout << "Somehow sprite still exists, freeing now." << endl;
        SDL_FreeSurface(sprite);
    }
}

bool Game::init(){
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );    

    if((screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF)) == NULL){
        return false;
    }

    sprite = SDL_LoadBMP("sprite.bmp");
    if(sprite == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;    
}

void Game::cleanup() {
    SDL_FreeSurface(sprite);
    SDL_Quit(); 
}

int Game::run() {   
    if(init() == false) {
        return -1;
    }
    loop();
    cleanup();
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Game g;
    return g.run();
}
```

Comment: Did you disable the copy constructor?  (Shouldn't be related to your issue)

Comment: Code looks fine to me, you'll need a [short self contained compilable example](http://sscce.org)

Comment: For Game()? No, but the full use is in `main` above, so I don't think it effects it. I think the issue is SDL_FreeSurface() doesn't set the pointer to NULL, but I'm still wondering about if a crash happens. For sscce, That's almost the entire source code. Other than unrelated quit on escape, and flip screen.

Comment: oh!  You're right, that's exactly the problem.  `SDL_FreeSurface` doesn't set the pointer to `NULL`.  (No freeing function I know of does that, so this is normal behavior.)  Post that as an answer I guess?  Or we'll close this as a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `sprite` being non-null after cleanup. Updated fix:

```
void Game::cleanup() {
    SDL_FreeSurface(sprite);
    sprite = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();
}
```